# Find the same differences between 2 sets of git commits

Tags: git, diff

We have a feature branch that has been failing some tests for some time. But when it was taken from master those tests passed.

Recently a few changes went into master and the same tests have started failing. There are a fair few unrelated changes but there must be something that has happened both in my feature branch and now master.

What I would like to do is take the 2 commits on my branch and the 5 or commits on master since the tests started failing and compare them, looking for a common change, it feels almost the inverse of a three way merge :p.

Is there a quick way to do this, currently I'm just eyeballing the cumulative git diff --name-status of the commits!

Comment: If you know the commit which makes the test fail but still can't find the change that causes it, your commits are too big.

Comment: Can you not just look at the diff between one commit in the master branch and one commit in the feature branch?

Comment: there are 2 commits in the feature branch that show up the failure in teamcity and 5 in master that are shown with the failure in TC. Both contain paket updates which have touched a lot of files and my guess is one of these touches have gone ary. Annoyingly they only fail on TC so I cant do git bisect locally

Comment: You could try to split the big commit into many small commits to see which of them starts to fail on TC.

Comment: its an option, but the tests take so long to run. and I have a hunch on the two respective commits (the two paket updates) so id really like to diff those with the last commit they both passe on looking for the common change. which is back to the inverse merge question :p. I guess I could git diff each commit with its previous then stick the result from both in kdiff....and look for where its the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` has a `--cherry-mark` option, which highlights commits that introduce the exact same changes :

```
# will mark with '=' commits cherry picked between the two branches :
git log --boundary --graph --cherry-mark --oneline master...feature
```

You may combine this with @mkrieger1's suggestion :

- in your local clone, split the big-ish commits on `master` and `feature` into smaller commits (perhaps have each commit update one single module ?),
- run `git log --boundary --graph --cherry-mark --oneline` on the two reworked branches

---

Note however that there would still be a lot of loopholes : suppose on o your so called "paket" was updated from `2.0.1` to `3.0.3` on `feature`, and from `2.0.1` to `3.0.5` on master, you wouldn't spot this with `--cherry-mark`.

You are still better off finding a way to run the failing test independently, and slicing through dependencies using `git bisect`.